# Low level mouse position

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to run a python script from ssh and i do not want to use X11.

I want to get mouse x,y position in this script.

I have tried to read /dev/input/mice but i cannot do anything with values. It looks like delta positions.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your mouse connected to your _local_ computer? The machine you connect to won't have any idea where your local mouse pointer is.

Comment: If you want to capture clicks in a terminal, start here: https://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html

Comment: no i mean mouse on distant computer. Curses does not work

Comment: How are you planning to physically move the mouse on a remote machine? And what does "curses does not work" mean? This is _definitely_ a valid solution.